# Web API No action was found on the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement webapi in existing website So here is my controller:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Http
Public Class UploadController
    Inherits ApiController
    Dim context As HttpContext
    <HttpPost>
    <Route("api/Upload/UploadFile", Name:="UploadFile")>
    Public Function UploadFile() As HttpResponseMessage
       //Some functional code
    End Function
```

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional})
    End Sub
```

This is the URL:

http://localhost:[portno]/api/Upload/UploadFile

When I run this getting a 404 error stating that No action was found on the controller 'Upload' that matches the name 'uploadfile'.

Comment: Attribute Routing is being used but it has not been enabled.  
Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: @Nikosi - Thanks for pointing the right one :) Great it worked